# Why Huawei Mate Series WebGL Max Array Texture Layers set at 256? This affect WebXR experience

Tags: webgl, huawei-mobile-services, webxr

## Huawei Mate Series & VR Glass WebGL Issue - Max Array Texture Layers set at 256

This issue has impacts on Huawei VR experiences but the bug is in the WebGL2 implementation so affecting all WebGL2 experiences if you use Huawei VR Glass.

To test, go to https://webglreport.com/?v=2

- Huawei Matebook laptop with Windows 10 (2022 year model) shows Max Array Texture Layers: 2048
- 2013 iMac shows Max Array Texture Layers: 2048
- Meta Quest 2 with QC XR2 SOC shows Max Array Texture Layers: 2048
  [image]
- iPhone 13 Pro Max shows Max Array Texture Layers: 2048
  [image]
- Nova 9 with EMUI 12 show Max Array Texture Layers: 2048
  [image]
- Mate 40 Pro with Harmony OS shows Max Array Texture Layers: **256**
  [image]
- Mate 40E with Harmony OS shows Max Array Texture Layers: **256**
  [image]
- Mate 30 Pro with Harmony OS shows Max Array Texture Layers: **256**
  [image]

Mate Series - 30 Pro, 40 Pro, 40E Huawei VR Glass has negative WebXR experience rendering 256+ texture layers.

https://constructarcade.com/game/archery-dungeon/

Huawei Mate 30 Pro/VR Glass - Wolvic

[image]

Meta Quest 2 - Wolvic

[image]

https://constructarcade.com/game/get-off-my-lawn/

Huawei Mate 30 Pro/VR Glass - Wolvic

[image]

Meta Quest 2 - Wolvic

[image]

#### Questions:

1. Why Huawei Mate Series WebGL Max Array Texture Layers set at 256?
2. Is this a bug in the OS (HarmonyOS) or the chipset (Kirin 990, 9000)?
3. Is there a way to fix it? 256 max layers are really low.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 256 is within spec, "why" can only be answered by the driver authors.